# Calculate the sum of negative-only_and_divisible_by_4 integers

Tags: assembly, masm32

I have a question that I am studying for my final exam. This is the question:

Write the program to calculate the sum of negative-only_and_divisible_by_4 integers entered (from keyboard) by the user until the user enters positive value 100.

Below is my code and it is working. I am wondering though is there a more efficient way to check to see if the number is divisible by 4.

```
.data

prompt BYTE "No Positive Numbers!",0
done BYTE "Finished..",0
notdivisible BYTE "This number is not divisble!",0

.code
start:


mov ebx,0

readin:
    call ReadInt
    cmp eax,100
    je finish
    cmp eax,0
    jg positive
    mov ecx,eax
    neg ecx
checkifdivisible:   
    sub ecx,4
    cmp ecx,0
    jl notdiv
    jg checkifdivisible
    je divisible

divisible:
    add ebx,eax
    LOOP readin

notdiv:
    mov edx,OFFSET notdivisible
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    jmp readin

positive:
    mov edx,OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    jmp readin

finish:
    call Crlf
    mov edx,OFFSET done
    call WriteString

    xchg ebx,eax
call Crlf
call WriteInt


exit
end start
```

Thank you all in advance for helping me make more efficient code! I feel like this answer is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number `n` is dividable by 4 if `n AND 3 == 0`. C check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void
is_div4(int32_t n)
{
  printf("%5d => 0x%08x, %d, %.2f\n",
    n, n, ((uint32_t) n & 3) == 0, (double) n / 4.0);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  is_div4(-100);
  is_div4(-4);
  is_div4(-102);
  is_div4(-338);
  is_div4(-108);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 -100 => 0xffffff9c, 1, -25.00
   -4 => 0xfffffffc, 1, -1.00
 -102 => 0xffffff9a, 0, -25.50
 -338 => 0xfffffeae, 0, -84.50
 -108 => 0xffffff94, 1, -27.00
```

Simple implementation:

```
    mov     eax, NUMBER
    and     eax, 0x3
    cmp     eax, 0
    jne     NotDividableBy4
    ; dividable by 4
NotDividableBy4:
    ;
```